# How to animate a whole list from inside div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im trying to make an overlay slider from and imagen, like, for example is an imagen and when I click it a slider will come from the same position of the imagen and shows a description.
I tried with jquery ui but now I have a problem implementing it. I want to use this effect with a lot of items, a list, so my problem is how I can make this script work for every item in the list, having into account that the href is inside the container div. I think this can explain my point more clear:
http://jsfiddle.net/viciosogb/tmzsZ

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for..

http://jsfiddle.net/tmzsZ/11/

Sort of hacky, but it works.

Basically, you need to use `$(this)` more so you grab the one that is clicked instead of targeting an ID, you need to target something that can be used multiple times, like a class.

Comment: Thanks so much, your code works like a charm, I hope I can give you a reputation but I need more reps

Comment: Glad i was able to help. You can choose my answer as best. :)